# How do I detect user input in c++?

Tags: c++, input

I'm trying to create a binary clock program that runs continually, and only quits when the user presses any key, aka any input.

Looking at other similar questions, detecting specific inputs is easy, but I would have to check for literally every single key for a similar effect.

```cpp
while(!input)
{
    //detect user input to make input=true
    //The clock program
}
```

Comment: On what OS? If linux look into ncurses.

Comment: Use OS specific APIs for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is really platform dependent.

On any Unix platform with curses and or ncurses:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  // Do something...
  printw("press any key to exit...");
  getch();
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Certainly, you need to link proper library during complation with `-lcurses` or `-lncurses`.

In Windows it's more complex:

```
#include <windows.h>

int PressAnyKey( const char *prompt )
{
  DWORD        mode;
  HANDLE       hstdin;
  INPUT_RECORD inrec;
  DWORD        count;
  char         default_prompt[] = "Press a key to continue...";

  /* Set the console mode to no-echo, raw input, */
  /* and no window or mouse events.              */
  hstdin = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
  if (hstdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
  || !GetConsoleMode( hstdin, &mode )
  || !SetConsoleMode( hstdin, 0 ))
    return 0;

  if (!prompt) prompt = default_prompt;

  /* Instruct the user */
  WriteConsole(
    GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ),
    prompt,
    lstrlen( prompt ),
    &count,
    NULL
    );

  FlushConsoleInputBuffer( hstdin );

  /* Get a single key RELEASE */
  do ReadConsoleInput( hstdin, &inrec, 1, &count );
  while ((inrec.EventType != KEY_EVENT) || inrec.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown);

  /* Restore the original console mode */
  SetConsoleMode( hstdin, mode );

  return inrec.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
}
```

Finally, possible portable way is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void PressAnyKeyToContinue()
{
   cout << "Press any key to continue...";
   cin.ignore();
   cin.get();
}
```

More on the topic: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7312/

Comment: Windows has [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/), which IIRC is a plain port of NCurses and whould work exactly the same.